# Unable to authenticate in Android Login Application using Mysql, php and Json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am very new to coding and I know its silly but I am starting with Android development directly and trying to make a simple Login Registration app and I found one good tutorial in Youtube to start with but somehow I stucked in Login activity.
I am using 000webhost.com as the server for registration and login and I am able to register in my app successfully and I think my Login php script is also running correctly because it is returning me an array as expected.
I don't have any idea why I am not able to login in my app. It is showing my hardcoded error message "Incorrect user details" always.
I am uploading the code.
Please help me out.
Thank you so much.

```
/* Its Login.java page */

package com.example.shashank.login_register;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button blogin;
EditText etemail, etpass;
TextView etregister;
UserLocalStore userLocalStore;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    etemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemail);
    etpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpass);

    etregister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etregister);
    etregister.setOnClickListener(this);

    blogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin);
    blogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.blogin:
            String email = etemail.getText().toString();
            String password = etpass.getText().toString();

            User user = new User(email, password);

            authenticate(user);
            break;

        case R.id.etregister:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
            break;
    }
}

private void authenticate(User user) {
    ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(this);
    serverRequests.fetchUserDataInBackground(user, new GetUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(User returnedUser) {
            if (returnedUser == null) {
                showErrorMessage();
            } else {
                logUserIn(returnedUser);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void showErrorMessage() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Incorrect user details");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    dialogBuilder.show();
}


private void logUserIn(User returnedUser) {
    userLocalStore.storeUserData(returnedUser);
    userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
}

 /* Its ServerRequests.java page */

 package com.example.shashank.login_register;

 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.util.Log;

 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
 import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
 import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams; 
 import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class ServerRequests {
  progressDialog;
  public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
  public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "<my server address>";


public ServerRequests(Context context) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
}

public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
    progressDialog.show();
    new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();

}

public void fetchUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
    progressDialog.show();
    new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();


}

public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.email));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", user.phone + ""));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(null);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}

public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.email));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");

        User returnedUser = null;

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

            if (jObject.length() != 0){
                Log.v("happened", "2");
                String name = jObject.getString("name");
                int phone = jObject.getInt("phone");

                returnedUser = new User(name, user.email, user.password, phone);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnedUser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(returnedUser);
        super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
    }
}
```

}

```
 /* Its User.java */
package com.example.shashank.login_register;

public class User {
     String name, email, password ;
     int phone;

public User (String name, String email, String password, int phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.phone = phone;
}
public User (String email, String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.name = "";
    this.password = password;
    this.phone = -1;
}
```

}

```
 /* Its UserLocalStore.java */

 package com.example.shashank.login_register;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;


 public class UserLocalStore {
 public static final String SP_NAME = "userdetails";
SharedPreferences userLocalDatabase;

public UserLocalStore(Context context) {
    userLocalDatabase = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, 0);
}

public void storeUserData(User user) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    spEditor.putString("name", user.name);
    spEditor.putString("email", user.email);
    spEditor.putString("password", user.password);
    spEditor.putInt("phone", user.phone);
    spEditor.commit();
}

public User getLoggedInUser() {
    String name = userLocalDatabase.getString("name", "");
    String email = userLocalDatabase.getString("email", "");
    String password = userLocalDatabase.getString("password", "");
    int phone = userLocalDatabase.getInt("phone", -1);

    User storedUser = new User(name, email, password, phone);

    return storedUser;
}

public void setUserLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    spEditor.putBoolean("loggedIn", loggedIn);
    spEditor.commit();
}

public boolean getUserLoggedIn() {
    if (userLocalDatabase.getBoolean("loggedIn", false) == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}


public void clearUserData() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    spEditor.clear();
    spEditor.commit();
}
```

}

```
  /* Its GetUserCallback.java */

  package com.example.shashank.login_register;


  interface GetUserCallback {

   public abstract void  done(User returnedUser);
  }



  /* Its FetchUserData.php */

  <?php
  $conn=mysqli_connect("<hostname>","<username name>","<password>","<db     name>");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection Failed:" .mysqli_connect_error());
}

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email, password from User");

$user = array();

while(mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $user["name"] = $name;
    $user["email"] = $email;
    $user["password"] = $password;
    $user["phone"] = $phone;
}

echo json_encode($user);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: We can't help fix what we can't see. You've provided nothing useful, like source code or even error messages.

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: welcome to programming. you have to be careful how you ask your questions on here. check out the tour. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Actually its my first post, so I didn't know how to upload the code but I have uploaded now..

Comment: someone plz help me out..